# Got This Is Null

Tags: angular, typescript

I got some weird error "this is null". I don't know what the problem is. This my demo [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geolocation-blitz-kuurmn) and example code as your reference.

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentLocation();
  }

  getCurrentLocation() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.weatherInfo(this.lat, this.lng)
},function(){
       this.origin = { lat: '3.140853', lng: '2.693207'};
       console.log(this.origin)
       this.weatherInfo(this.origin.lat, this.origin.lng)
})



  }
  weatherInfo(lat, lng){
    console.log(lat, lng);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an arrow function (`() => {` instead of `function() {`) due to the required scope:

```
getCurrentLocation() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.weatherInfo(this.lat, this.lng)
}, () => { // Here
       this.origin = { lat: '3.140853', lng: '2.693207'};
       console.log(this.origin)
       this.weatherInfo(this.origin.lat, this.origin.lng)
})
```

Maybe worth a read: [Understanding "this" in javascript with arrow functions](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc) or [Arrow functions and the ‘this’ keyword](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881#.59q9th108)

Answer (score 2):

You either need to bind this on your anonymous function or write it as an arrow function so your reference to this remains.

Option 1:

```
getCurrentLocation() {
// Your Method
}, this.logging().bind(this))

logging() {
// Do something
}
```

Option 2:

```
getCurrentLocation() {
// Your Method
}, () => {// Do something})
```